# Do shared variables between threads always require protection ?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, race-condition

Lets say I have two threads reading and modifying a bool / int "state". The reads and writes are guaranteed to be atomic by the processor.

```
Thread 1:

if (state == ENABLED)
{
    Process_Data()
}

Thread 2:

state = DISABLED
```

In this case yes the thread 1 can read the state and go into it's "if" to Process_Data and then Thread2 can change state. But it isn't incorrect at that point to still go on to Process_Data. Yes if we peek into the hood we have an inconsistency of state being DISABLED and us entering the Process_Data function. But after its executed the next time Thread1 executes it will get state = DISABLED and not Process_Data.

My question is do I still need a lock in both these threads to make Thread1's check-state-and-process atomic and Thread2's write atomic (wrt to Thread 1) ?

Comment: As a general rule, there is never* a case where you will _always_ need something. (* never, being another absolute, is usually wrong.) It's really going to depend on your use-case. As you've already stated, you don't mind running `Process_Data` when `state` is in fact `DISABLED`, so you don't need a lock. That's assuming that `Process_Data` isn't going to run into some conflict with whatever is happening on Thread 2, of course.

Comment: "Atomic by the processor" just means "torn reads/writes won't happen".  That has nothing to do with memory visibility (read up on cache coherence).

Comment: `state = DISABLED`, without any compiler or hardware barriers, migth lead to thread1 never, ever, seeing the effect of thread2 doing `state = DISABLED`

Answer (score 0):

You've addressed the atomicity concerns.  However, in modern processors, you have to worry not just about atomicity, but also memory visibility.

For example, thread 1 is executing on one processor, and reads ENABLED from `state` - from its processor's cache.

Meanwhile, thread 2 is executing on a different processor, and writes DISABLED to `state` on its processor's cache.

Without further code - in some languages, for example, declaring `state` volatile - the DISABLED value may not get flushed to main memory for a long time.  It may never get flushed to main memory if thread 2 changes the value back to ENABLED eventually.

Meanwhile, even if the DISABLED value is flushed to main memory, thread 1 may never pick it up, instead continuing to use its cached value of ENABLED indefinitely.

Generally if you want to share values between threads, it's better to do so explicitly using the appropriate mechanisms for the programming language and environment that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to answer your question generically. If the specification for the language, compiler, threading library and/or platform you are using says you need protection, then you do. If it says you don't, then you don't. I believe *every* threading library or multi-threading implementation specifies rules for sane use and sharing of data. If yours doesn't, it's a piece of junk that is impossible to use reliably and you should get a better one.

Do not make the mistake of thinking, "This is safe because I can't think of any way it can go wrong." Or "I tested this, and I couldn't get it to fail, so it's safe." That kind of thinking produces fragile code that tends to fail when you change compiler options, upgrade your CPU, or run the program on a different platform. Follow the specifications for the tools you are using.

Comment: That said, adding protection just because its "safer" is wrong in my opinion. My question was aimed at finding whether an inconsistency of internal state for an instance is acceptable if no data corruption is happening.

Comment: What platform or threading library says that you can have an inconsistency of internal state but no data corruption? Most of the ones I've seen either fully specify behavior or document it as undefined/unspecified. This middle ground is, in most cases, purely mythical.